# How could i include the full url using rest api

Tags: rest

```
var queryUrl = appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/webs?$select=Title,Url&@target='" + hostweburl + "'";
```

i want to include the hole url like this

> http:///site/_api/

and so on
(my value of the query gets undenified?